# My video card doesn't show up in control panel.Can't load drivers

Tags: graphics-card

I'm running

- **OS** Windows XP 64bit.
- **Video card** Nvidia GT 710 PCIE
- **Motherboard** Gigabyte GA-78LMTUSB motherboard

Comment: @Thulashitharan how can the card be dead if it works?  I provided the real answer below.

Comment: @Keltari The question did not specify whether the card works ............i thought he/she was presently running on integrated graphics...........my bad i should have asked for clarification :) .

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it was a driver issue.There exist drivers which support your video card and win xp 64bit .You can get your required drivers using NVIDIA advanced driver search tool. These drivers are outdated but will work.[Click here to view the driver](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/105041/en-us)

Comment: You are correct.  This driver did not come up in the regular geforce driver search.